# error : invalid input syntax for type timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, database-migration

I have a issue when I migrate table from one database to another database table. I am using PostgreSQL database.

The issue:

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "31:57.7"
LINE 2:      VALUES ('52','GUIDO Layouts','','f','47','31:57.7','34:...

In statement:

INSERT INTO "public"."projects" ("id","name","description","public","parent_id","created_at","updated_at","identifier","lft","rgt","templated","active")
                    VALUES ('52','GUIDO Layouts','','f','47','31:57.7','34:31.5','guido-layouts','81','82','f','t')
```

I checked both table structure are same. both column(create_at) using ***timestamp without time zone***
and I tried using `now()`

please help me

Comment: `31:57.7` is not a valid timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

`timestamp` is a `datetime` so you need a date component to make it work with a `timestamp` field. You can use it as a `time`, so:

`'31:57.7'::time 00:31:57.7`.

You have two choices:

1. If you want to stick with using just time, change the column type to `time`.
2. Keep the timestamp type and change the value to a timestamp(datetime).